# Project Euler #60 Prime pair sets

Tags: python

The problem is as below:

> The primes 3, 7, 109, and 673, are quite remarkable. By taking any two primes and concatenating them in any order the result will always be prime. For example, taking 7 and 109, both 7109 and 1097 are prime. The sum of these four primes, 792, represents the lowest sum for a set of four primes with this property.
>
> Find the lowest sum for a set of five primes for which any two primes concatenate to produce another prime.

```
%%time
import itertools
import time

t1 = time.time()

def prime():

    yield 3
    yield 7

    for i in itertools.count(11, 2):
        e = int(i ** .5) + 1
        for j in range(2, e + 1):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield i


def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    e = int(n ** .5) + 1
    for i in range(2, e + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True


def power_up(n):
    # helper function return the next 10 power
    i = 1
    while 1:
        if n < i:
            return i
        i*=10


def conc(x,y):
    # helper function check if xy and yz is prime
    if not is_prime((x*power_up(y))+y):
        return False
    else:
        return is_prime(y*power_up(x)+x)
    
def conc3(x,y,z): # not use, it did not improve the performance 
    a = conc(x,y)
    if not a:
        return False
    b = conc(x,z)
    if not b:
        return False
    c = conc(y,z)
    if not c:
        return False
    return True
    
        
    

one = []
two = []
three = []
four = []
found = 0

for i in prime():
    if found:
        break
    try:
        if i > sum_:
            break
    except:
        pass
    one += [i]
    for j in one[:-1]:  # on the fly list
        if conc(i,j):
            two += [[i, j]]
            for _, k in two: # check against k only if it is in a two pair
                if _ == j:
                    for x in [i, j]:
                        if not conc(x,k):
                            break
                    else:
                        three += [[i, j, k]]
                        for _, __, l in three:
                            if _ == j and __ == k:

                                for x in [i, j, k]:
                                    if not conc(x,l):
                                        break
                                else:
                                    four += [[i, j, k, l]]
                                    # print(i, j, k, l)
                                    for _, __, ___, m in four:
                                        if _ == j and __ == k and ___ == l:
                                            for x in [i, j, k, l]:
                                                if not conc(x,m):
                                                    break
                                            else:
                                                a = [i, j, k, l, m]
                                                t2 = time.time()
                                                try:
                                                    if (
                                                        sum(a) < sum_
                                                    ):  # assign sum_ with the first value found
                                                        sum_ = sum(a)
                                                except:
                                                    sum_ = sum(a)
                                                print(
                                                    f"the sum now is {sum(a)}, the sum of [{i}, {j}, {k}, {l}, {m}], found in {t2-t1:.2f}sec"
                                                )
                                                if i > sum_:
                                                    # if the first element checked is greater than the found sum, then we are sure we found it,
                                                    # this is the only way we can be sure we found it.
                                                    # it took 1 and a half min to find the first one, and confirm that after 42min.
                                                    # my way is not fast, but what I practised here is to find the number without a guessed boundary
                                                    
                                                    found = 1
                                                    print(
                                                        f"the final result is {sum_}"
                                                    )
```

I found the first candidate in 75 sec which I think is to long. I want to see if anyone can give me some suggestion on how to improve the performance.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is to look again at the primality testing. There's no need to test divisibility by every number up to the square root: it suffices to test divisibility by the primes up to the sqrt. Add a cache and you'll probably beat the minute. For something even faster, look at precomputing all the primes in one sieve. If you want to avoid hard-coding the limit of the sieve, try segmenting it: E.g. sieve up to 1000, and if you need more then sieve 1001-2000, using your knowledge of the primes up to sqrt(2000); etc.

Then the actual search looks rather complicated, and I'm not sure it isn't doing more work than necessary. Have you tried just storing the pairs as a dict from larger to set of smaller and checking triples of those which pair with the current prime under consideration?